# Aplicar hover em linha de outra tabela no HTML

Tags: javascript, css

Em meu HTML existem duas tabelas separadas, e em todas minhas tags `tr` contem um `hover` aplicado no CSS.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: ao passar o mouse em uma tag `tr` de uma tabela é possível aplicar o hover na `tr` da outra tabela?

É possível isso somente com CSS ou precisamos de JavaScript também?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

th{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}

td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr:hover{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>   
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>   
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Por que não usa uma tabela só?

Comment: é para um projeto, tem que ser tabelas separadas. São tabelas de segmentos diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não dá pra fazer só com CSS, pois não há controle de qual é a linha correspondente em outra tabela. Precisa-se de uma regra para estabelecer isso.

No exemplo abaixo, reimplementei o hover do CSS no JavaScript com os eventos `mouseover` e `mouseout`, ligando e desligando uma classe CSS. Perceba também que precisei adicionar um atributo `id` às tabelas.

O código JavaScript é simples e sem dependências. Ao "ligar" (highlight) uma linha, acha-se a linha irmã (correspondente em uma tabela diferente) e a liga também.

Lembrando que as tabelas precisam ter o **MESMO** número de linhas.

```js
function acharTabelasIrmas(tabela) {
  return document.querySelectorAll("table:not(#" + tabela.id + ")");
}

function acharLinhasIrmas(linha) {
  var tabelasIrmas = acharTabelasIrmas(linha.closest("table"));
  return Array.from(tabelasIrmas).map(function(tabela) {
    return tabela.rows[linha.rowIndex];
  });
}

function ligarLinha(linha) {
  var linhasParaLigar = acharLinhasIrmas(linha);
  linhasParaLigar.push(linha)
  linhasParaLigar.forEach(function(linhaParaLigar) {
    linhaParaLigar.classList.add("highlight");
  });
 }

function desligarLinha(linha) {
  var linhasParaDesligar = acharLinhasIrmas(linha);
  linhasParaDesligar.push(linha)
  linhasParaDesligar.forEach(function(linhaParaDesligar) {
    linhaParaDesligar.classList.remove("highlight");
  });}

window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr").forEach(function(elemento) {
    elemento.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      ligarLinha(elemento);
    });


    elemento.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
      desligarLinha(elemento);
    });
  });
};
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="tb1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>   
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>

<table id="tb2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>   
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
  <table id="tb3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>   
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: caso fosse mais de duas tabelas como seria?

Comment: Pronto! Modifiquei a resposta com mais tabelas.